# How Update customer invoice details using stripe api

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I want to update Customer invoice Details, the details which are shown in the picture bellow

[image]

I've researched and the documentation says use this code update the ivoice

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("sk_test_hi3LvqzVUrxrlBwqdFukAK4Q");

var options = new CustomerUpdateOptions {
  Description = "Customer for jenny.rosen@example.com"
};

var service = new CustomerService();
Customer customer = service.Update("cus_EQL4cC8XJAO4YJ", options);
```

This code works fine but when I try to use `CustomerUpdateOptions` to update for example `Address Line 1`
I can't find this property in this class

```
    [JsonProperty("account_balance")]
    public int? AccountBalance { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("business_vat_id")]
    public string BusinessVatId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public string SourceToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public SourceCard SourceCard { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("coupon")]
    public string Coupon { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("default_source")]
    public string DefaultSource { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("metadata")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }
```

All the properties I have in `CustomerUpdateOptions` are the above mentioned. 
How to update other fields specified in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you submit your changes on Stripe dashboard, you would see the following request body

```
{
  "account_balance": "0",
  "description": "Customer for Testing",
  "invoice_prefix": "KarenPrefix",
  "shipping": {
    "phone": "+12016262852",
    "name": "",
    "address": {
      "line1": "",
      "line2": "",
      "city": "",
      "state": "",
      "postal_code": "",
      "country": ""
    }
  },
  "tax_info": {
    "tax_id": "",
    "type": "vat"
  },
  "invoicing": {
    "email_to": [
      "test@test.com"
    ],
    "email_cc": [
      "test2@test.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

So it maps to the request body shown in Stripe [API doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update).

The `CustomerUpdateOptions looks likes the following, refer to [doc](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/17600cb35e20712df058e9a9819b401d7315cd19/src/Stripe.net/Services/Customers/CustomerUpdateOptions.cs#L7)

```
namespace Stripe
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class CustomerUpdateOptions : BaseOptions
    {
        [JsonProperty("account_balance")]
        public long? AccountBalance { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("coupon")]
        public string Coupon { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("default_source")]
        public string DefaultSource { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("invoice_prefix")]
        public string InvoicePrefix { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("metadata")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Metadata { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shipping")]
        public ShippingOptions Shipping { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("source")]
        public string SourceToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("source")]
        public CardCreateNestedOptions SourceCard { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tax_info")]
        public CustomerTaxInfoOptions TaxInfo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("validate")]
        public bool? Validate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So you would set the `ShippingOptions` to update the `address.line1`

Hope it helps

Comment: I was using an old api version, after update everything is ok.  Thanks a lot.